# Basic API Login Authentication with React-Native

Tags: react-native, authentication

I need to make basic API login authentication with email and password, but I didn't find good working examples. I need help...

1- It should make a POST request to URL of the base
2- The email and password needs to be as variables like "...this.state.email/this.state.password" (something like that) so then I can set them in the input fields like "...this.handleEmail/.thishandlePassword" (something like that I think)
3- I need a log in the console or response from the api for success or fail authentication
4- Need to show error if the fields are empty or there is no user with this email or password

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {

  constructor(){
           super();
           this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            result: false,
           }
       }

    _userLogin() {
         let email = this.state.username;
         let password = this.state.password;
         if (email && password) { 
           fetch("https://URL/api/login", {
             method: "POST",
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
               email: email,
               password: password,
             })
           })
           .then((response) => response.json())
           .then((responseData) => {
             console.log(responseData),
             this._onValueChange(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.id_token)
           })
           .done();
           renderResults();
         }
       }

       renderResults = () => {
           if(responseData){
                this.setState({
                    result: true
                })
           }
       }

       handleEmail = (text) => {
             this.setState({ email: text })
       }

       handlePassword = (text) => {
             this.setState({ password: text })
       }

  render() {

    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent"/>
        <Content>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.imageWave} source={require("./pictures/Group723.png")}/>
          <Text style={styles.headerTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.boldHeaderText}>Hotel </Text> 
              <Text style={styles.thinHeaderText}>Maids</Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
          <Text style={styles.loginThinText}>Log In</Text>      
        <CardView
          cardElevation={3}
          cardMaxElevation={4}
          cornerRadius={15}
           style={{
            marginTop: 1,
            width: 322,
            height: 104,
            alignSelf: 'center',
          }}>

        <View style={styles.textAreaLogin}>
        {this.state.result ? <View></View> : <View>
          <TextInput  
          keyboardType="email-address" 
          style={styles.textAreaEmail} 
          placeholderTextColor="#C8C8C8" 
          placeholder="Username-HK"
          onChange={this.handleEmail}
          />
          
          <TextInput 
          secureTextEntry={true} 
          style={styles.textAreaPassword} 
          placeholderTextColor="#C8C8C8" 
          placeholder="Password-HK"
          onChange={this.handlePassword}
          />
          <Button onPress={() => {this._userLogin(); this.props.navigation.navigate(IntroScreen);}}>LOGIN</Button>
          </View>}
        </View>
        </CardView>
```

Comment: So, what's exactly the problem? You only need to materialize what you said.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I doesn't work :D I'll show my code now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're connected to a backend that's sending you the appropriate responses

```js
function LoginScreen(props) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const onChangeEmail = (text) => setEmail(text);
    const onChangePassword = (text) => setPassword(text);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                // You can navigate here as well
                navigation.navigate('SomeScreen');
                return json.movies;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput value={email} onChangeText={onChangeEmail} />
            <TextInput
                value={password}
                onChangeText={onChangePassword}
                autoCompleteType="password"
                textContentType="password"
                secureTextEntry
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit}>
                <Text>Log In</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: You sure it's onChangeText and not only onChange ?

Comment: Sorry 1-How is going to happened in class not in function 2-how to add two functions in onPress for the button after authentication is success to navigate to screen with react-navigation?

Comment: @YoanIvanov yep it's onChangeText https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext

Comment: @YoanIvanov check updated code above to perform navigation after a successful API call

Comment: Thanks I'll try it

Comment: can't find variable useState ?